# Eigenvalues of product of unitaries

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, unitary-representations

Consider $d\times d$ unitary matrices $U, \, V, \, W$ such that
$$
W=UV.
$$
Suppose that the eigenvalues of $U$ and $V$ are $(e^{i\theta_1},\cdots,e^{i\theta_d})$ and $(e^{i\phi_1},\cdots,e^{i\phi_d})$.

> **Question.** What are the possible eigenvalues of $W$?

Answer (score 4):

The state of the art appears to be reflected in

- [Thompson, R. C. "On the eigenvalues of a product of unitary matrices I." *Linear and Multilinear Algebra* **2**, 13 (1974)](https://doi.org/10.1080/03081087408817038)
- [Chau, H. F. and Lam, Y. T. "Elementary proofs of two theorems involving arguments of eigenvalues of a product of two unitary matrices." *Journal of Inequalities and Applications* 18 (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-18)